# Why is det(AB)=det(A)det(B) true for all matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Neither did our professor nor book give a proof of this fact, but just in case I need to know that.

Comment: When neither your professor nor your book prove it, that may be a sign to look elsewhere.  For example Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Multiplicativity_and_matrix_groups).  Or it may be a sign that the proof will occur later.

Comment: While I suspect this question is somewhat too broad and unmotivated, I'll give you a big hint: what does the derivative of a linear transformation _represent_?

Comment: (That's not to say that _you're_ unmotivated! Just that the question comes out of nowhere with no background information.)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I don’t see the point of this question

Comment: This is true for all square matrices, not all matrices.

Comment: @Thinking because with the 'geometric' definition of the derivative of a transform, along with the understanding that $AB$ is the transform that corresponds to performing transform $B$, then performing transform $A$ on the result, the result becomes (IMHO) easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

First you prove this for all $B$ and all elementary matrices $A$  (an elementary matrix is a matrix that is obtained from $I$ by using one elementary row operation).

Next, you show that multiplying by $A$ is the same as applying said elementary row operation.

After that, you study the effect of each elementary row operation on the determinant. Then you have proved the theorem for: arbitrary $B$, and elementary matrix $A$.

After that, you show that every invertible matrix is a product of elementary matrices. This ensures that the theorem is true when $A$ is invertible.

When $A$ is not invertible, treat that case separately. (You have to show that the determinant is zero, once again, by row-reducing.)

Answer (score 0):

The result known as [Cauchy-Binet Formula](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cauchy-Binet_Formula) and holds in a more general context for $A$ m-by-n and $B$ n-by-m matrices and of course also in the special case of $m=n$ for square matrices.

Comment: How do you defined the determinant on a non-square matrix ?

Comment: @Thinking refer to the given link for the definition